# Is the stake pool fixed fee cost once per epoch or per every block won?

Tags: stake-pool, fee, rewards

Is the stake pool fixed fee cost, or min fee currently 340 ada, once per epoch, or once per block won?

Answer (score 2):

The fixed fee and percentage fee are calculated once per epoch if the pool mints at least one block.

These fees are taken out of the total rewards amount that the pool earned that epoch, and the remainder is distributed to all delegates at amounts proportional to their stake within that pool.

Comment: Almost, the remainder is still deducted by the dynamic/ margin fees if those are set to a percent greater than 0 before the delegates receive their proportional rewards.